# Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync() does not work on the web and native

Tags: javascript, react-native, web, camera, expo

Please provide the following:
1. SDK Version: 36
2. Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): all

I am working on a `react-native` application and I want to get the camera types (front and back) on the web and native.

In the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#cameragetavailablecameratypesasync-string), it is written:

> `Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync(): string[]`
>   Returns a list of camera types `['front', 'back']`. This is useful for desktop browsers which only have front-facing cameras.
>
> ```
> import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
>
> const types = await Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync();
> ```

This is my `Camera.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { FAB, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

export default function CoreCamera() {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);
  const [types, setTypes] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const types = await Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync();
      alert(JSON.stringify(types));
      setTypes(types);
      if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
        setHasPermission(true);
      } else {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={type}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              setType(
                type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
              );
            }}
          >
            <FAB
              style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}
              icon="camera-switch"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </View>
  );
}
```

On Android, it gives me the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The method or property expo-camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync is not available on android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]
```

On iOS, it gives me the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The method or property expo-camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync is not available on ios, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies properly?]
```

On the web, it gives me the following error:

```
bundle.js:73612 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAvailableCameraTypesAsync' of undefined
    at getAvailableCameraTypesAsync$ (bundle.js:73612)
    at tryCatch (bundle.js:185959)
```

I have tried to replace:

```
-import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
+import Camera from 'expo-camera/build/Camera';
```

Now the alert shows an empty array on the web.

How can I test the presence of the back camera on the web with expo?

expo-camera version 8.0.0

**edit**

I have tried to update `expo-camera@8.2.0` and it is worst:

Answer (score 0):

Remember you have to check if in web browser are available. Also at [expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera) say that it's only works in web, the error message tells you. You can use:

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

if (await Camera.isAvailableAsync()) {
    const types = await Camera.getAvailableCameraTypesAsync();
    // save values into on types
}
```

You use this inside a function in useEffect at your component to figure out. 
Sorry for bad english :.

Comment: Have you tested it? I have a webcam and I can take pictures with it, it is available, I only call this method for the web, I don't check if it's available async, but I expect in my situation to at least have the front camera while the method is returning an error of missing function on the web. I don't feel your answer will help to solve that.